# Getting the path to a users documents folder on Linux and MacOSX

Tags: linux, macos, matlab, shell, operating-system

I'm currently developing a GUI using Matlab and I need to get the directory of the standard document folder of the user. Under windows I use this:

```
command = 'echo %USERPROFILE%\Documents';
[status,docpath] = system(command);
```

and it works perfectly. Now I planned on doing the same for Linux and Mac with the system(command), but I have no idea what the actual command must look like under these OS.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: coming from a windows background, it might be a bit difficult to get adjusted to linux. But that doesn't mean that you shouldn't google before posting a question here. This is a tad easy one. :-

Comment: This question has not been properly asked.  Refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.

Comment: @sjsam Believe me, I tried to find a solution on google before creating an account here specifically to ask that question. Unfortunately the results I found only refered to getting the path of a specific folder when the username is already known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux the tilde `~` folder is used instead of `%USERPROFILE%`.

`~` is, usually the,equivalent `/home/username` in which you'll find the 'Documents' folder as in your example.
The folder pointed by '~' will be adapted in function of the user.

[Here is an example on what is on '~'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN3bl.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ~/Documents
```

should do the job. The `~` undergoes [[ tilde expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html#Tilde-Expansion-1).